# Ink canvas byte array image binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ink canvas, where user can draw on it, and I save it as byte array into database as image:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    if (icPad.Strokes.Count > 0)
    {
        icPad.Strokes.Save(ms, true);
        picture = ms.ToArray();
```

How can I retrieve bind the byte array into image?

Edited:

I use this code below to convert to BitmapImage:

```
    if (imageData == null || imageData.Length == 0) return null;

    var image = new BitmapImage();
    try
    {
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream(imageData))
        {
            mem.Position = 0;
            image.BeginInit();
            image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.UriSource = null;
            image.StreamSource = mem;
            image.EndInit();
        }

        image.Freeze();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return image;
}
```

I get an error:

> No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.

Comment: What you are saving is a [StrokeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.ink.strokecollection.aspx), not an image. See the *Remarks* section of the [Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590544.aspx) method: "The Save method saves the StrokeCollection as Ink Serialized Format (ISF)".

Comment: Will ink.Save(PersistenceFormat.Gif); save as image?

Comment: What is `ink.Save(PersistenceFormat.Gif)`? You would have to tell which method (which class) you mean.